# Spring Security Login via DWR (Direct Web Remoting)

Tags: java, spring-security, dwr

I am looking for a way to login/logout users with DWR, so that I could just create a DWR bean with methods login and logout.

```
public class AuthorizationHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    public Map<String, String> loginUser(String userName, String password) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        if (userRepository.validate(userName, password)) {
            // login the user here       
            map.put("success", true);
            map.put("redirect", ...);
        } else {
            map.put("success", false);
        }
        return map;
    }


    public Map<String, String> logoutUser() {
        // logout the user here
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("success", "ok");
        return map;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to work with users and to log them in/out programmatically. All the tutorial uses xml based configuration, but what is behind is sort of hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of my application I had a similar requirement, please find the steps I followed

```
public void authenticateSession(HttpSession session, UserDetails user) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            user, authRequest.getCredentials(), user.getAuthorities());
    result.setDetails(authRequest.getDetails());

    SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    ctx.setAuthentication(result);

    session.setAttribute(
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY,
            TextEscapeUtils.escapeEntities(user.getUsername()));
    session.setAttribute(
            HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
            ctx);

    AuthenticationSuccessEvent event = new AuthenticationSuccessEvent(
            result);
    applicationContext.publishEvent(event);
}
```

This method authenticates the passed session with the passed user object.

In your case you have to obtain the `UserDetails` object and pass it to this method along with the current session.

You can use the `UserDetailsService` interface to load the `UserDetails`.

Comment: That looks quite nice. However I don't know how to correctly get the HttpSession with DWR. I tried `HttpSession session = WebContextFactory.get().getSession();`, but that only leads to CSRF attack errors raised by DWR just after the getSession method is called. Also - do I need to access the applicationContext and publish the events?

Comment: I'm not familiar with DWR, but in that case you can get hold of the request object and create a new session with `request.getSession(true)` then sent the `session id` back to the client and set the `JSESSIONID` cookie with this value.

Comment: If you supply HttpSession in the java method called by DWR, DWR itself will inject the session object.  This works for WebRequest and contexts as well.  See the documentation here for a caveat as well:  http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/javaapi.html